# $G \subset Map(S,S)$, a subset closed under composition, has a unique projector

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm having trouble showing that:

For $G \subset Map(S,S)$ a subset closed under composition (i.e. for all $f,g \in G: f\circ g \in G$) such that $(G, \circ)$ is a group, $G$ has a unique projector $p: S \rightarrow S$, $p \circ p=p$.

My exercise sheet also states that:

Let $p$ be the unique projector in $G$ and let $T=p(S)$ be its image. Let $q=p|_{S\backslash T}:S\rightarrow T$ be the restriction of $p$ to $S\backslash T$.

I can't see how this information is relevant to the question. What I was thinking of doing was claiming that there was a second projector $p'$ in $G$ and then proving that $p=p'$. I tried to do something with the fact that $p \circ p' \in G$ but it didn't seem to lead me anywhere.

I'd really appreciate a hint (or a shove) in the right direction!

Comment: In a group, what does $x^2 = x$ tell you about $x$?

Comment: Then x is the identity element of the group?

Comment: Right. So if you have two projectors, $p, p'$, then ...?

Comment: Oh! So if both $p$ and $p'$ are projectors then both of them would be identity elements and $p = p' \circ p = p'$?

Comment: You could also appeal to the general uniqueness of the identity element in groups, but repeating the proof works too.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I don't need to show that x would be the identity element if $x^2 =x$, because that equality only holds for the identity, right?

Comment: In a group, you can cancel, or multiply with the inverse, $x^2 = x \Rightarrow x = x^{-1}x^2 = x^{-1}x = e$.

Comment: Ok, does this mean that the projector of a group always the identity element?

Comment: What would "the projector of a group" in general be? Here, we are dealing with maps $S\to S$, and a projector is a map $p \colon S \to S$ with $p\circ p = p$. A projector is, by definition, an idempotent map. Now the fact is that a group contains exactly one idempotent element, namely the identity element. One direction was shown above, the other, $e^2 = e$, is immediate from the definition of the identity element.

Comment: So, the information about $T$ is actually not relevant for the proof that the group has a unique projector?